# NgOnit() not triggerd

Tags: typescript, angular8

I am on home component, and when go to the login page component then i came back

```
loginForm() {
     localStorage.setItem('isLogin' , 'true' )
     const data = this.UserLoginForm.value;
     console.log(data);
     this.user.email = data.email;
     this.user.password = data.password;
     console.log(this.user);
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
      }
```

from login page component to home component ngOninit not triggered

```
ngOnInit() {
        let data = localStorage.getItem('isLogin');
        console.log(data);
        if(data === 'true'){
         console.log('working');
         this.isLogin = true;
        }
       }
```

also in whole project implemented lazy loading.

Comment: Check if the home component is destroyed (by implementing onDestroy), if not onInit won't be called.

Comment: does your component implements OnInit?

Comment: Yes it's implemented but when we back from login then ngOnInit not called then i have to manually refresh it.

Comment: ngOnInit is only fired once during the first load of a component. It's not meant to be used for subsequent page loads. You may find some info in [this link](https://blog.angularindepth.com/refresh-current-route-in-angular-512a19d58f6e) about refetching data on same URL.